# React routing with spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, react-router

I'm making an webapp using react and spring mvc. I've got 2 questions while making it.

1. How do you request mapping? 
   I want to map all the uris but resources and apis into index.jsp, react SPA entry.

   - resouce uris start with /res
   - api uris start with /api
2. How do you response url that react recognize. I mean If you put /examples/1 on your browser, then the web server retutns index.jsp with uri /examples/1 so that react redirects itself to /examples/1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a controller like this,

```
@RequestMapping("/api/**")
public ApiResult api(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    return apiProxy.proxy(request, reponse);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/**", method=HTTPMethod.GET)
public String index(){
    return "index"
}
```

and setup spring config like this.

```
<mvc:resource mapping="/res/**" location="/res/" order="-1"/>
```

**order -1 is very important.**
It makes spring to check first the request url matches with resource mapping.

Comment: can you advise how did your web.xml looked like?

Comment: @kvatashydze hmm I don't remember it actually. But I'm sure that I had a servlet of `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` and mapped it to all the urls.